# AngularJS 2 Http get method is appending localhost:3000 by default to url

Tags: angular, http, get

I am using the http module in angular v2.4.0. While using the http get method, i noticed that the localhost:3000 is being added to the specified url. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: are you trying to access url without `http` in the beginning? Then it tends to do that, but if you use "complete" url, starting with `http://....` it should work? :)

Comment: Yes it works. Actually, I had tried this earlier but I was parsing the response wrong so my log was showing undefined. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out :)